# Controlling the output of a json feed

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I'm trying to pull out a json feed from a Wordpress query. I need the JSON to be formatted [{"id":"1","title":"title"},{"id":"2","title":"title2"}]

The json_encode function is not pulling out this specific format: Items are not separated by commas and I'm also missing the initial and final [ ]

I made this code echoing those missing elements, which works good, but the final comma, because of the echo is making the script reading it to fail.

```
<?php 
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'location',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);

$locations = new WP_Query($args);

    if($locations -> have_posts()):
        echo '[';
        while ($locations->have_posts()) : $locations->the_post();
        $coords = get_field('coordinates');
        $pid = get_the_ID();
        $json["id"] = $pid;
        $json["name"] = get_the_title();
        $json["lat"] = $coords['lat'];
        $json["lng"] = $coords['lng'];
        $json["address"] = get_field('address');
        $json["address2"] = get_field('address_2');
        $json["city"] = get_field('city');
        $json["state"] = get_field('state');
        $json["postal"] = get_field('zip_code');
        $json["phone"] = get_field('office_phone');
        $json["fax"] = get_field('office_fax');
        $json["web"] = apply_filters('the_permalink', get_permalink());      
        echo json_encode($json);
        echo ',';
    endwhile;
        echo ']';
    endif;

?>
```

I know that echoing those elements is not the correct way to do it, and I'm doing something wrong on the encode, that's why it's pulling out without the right formatting.

I have been researching for days and I couldn't find a way to create a json_encode echoing and at the same time controlling the fields that it will show from a wordpress query.

I appreciate in advance any solution/lead to solve this.

Comment: And what's wrong exactly with the wrong output? -- Use a cumulative output array, and append the individual dicts via `$result[] = $json;`, then only json_encode the final `$result` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding it wrong in your loop. What you want to do is create an array, and present that array as json.

```
if($locations -> have_posts()):
    $data = array();
    while ($locations->have_posts()) : $locations->the_post();

    // add the location stuff to the $data array
    $data[] = array(
        'id' => $pid,
        'name' => get_the_title(),
        // etc....
    );

    endwhile;
// present your json
echo json_encode($data);

endif;
```